# Find all resources (users) that has a schema extension property set to null

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a scenario were we need to extend the existing schema in AAD for users to support our use case. As soon as a new user has been created (we do not control this process) we want to attach some additional information to the object. We also want to attach information to all the already existing user objects. We though the schema extension in the Graph API would solve this issue for us.

I've added a schema definition based on the [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups). Our extension got the name **ext7sumrsqd_policies** and have the following properties:

- IsHandled (boolean)
- SuggestedOwner (string)

After the extension was created I wanted to find all users that does not have the new "property" set (imagine a sync that is running on an intervall and want to check for new users that has not yet been handled).

Tried the following query first: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=ext7sumrsqd_policies eq null`

However the Graph API does not support filter with null.

Therefore tried to filter on any of the properties on the new extension:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=ext7sumrsqd_policies/IsHandled eq false`
- `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=ext7sumrsqd_policies/IsHandled eq true`

However this filter never returns any user that has ext7sumrsqd_policies=null.

Are there any way you can filter the Graph API for resources that is currently missing a schema extension property or where the property is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated filtering by null is not supported. You might try creating a second schema extension such as ext7sumrsqd_hasPolicies that specifies if ext7sumrsqd_policies is null or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Nice idea, however I still run into problems since I cannot create a filter that will only get me the user that does not have ext7sumrsqd_hasPolicies yet (example, a new user). Since I cannot provide a default value for my extension any new user will have <extensionName> : null which makes it impossible to filter for it.

Comment: @Masus you will have to always set such value for every user. No the most optimal but it will do the job.

Comment: Seems like Your suggestion is the only way. Far from ideal because we will need to query for all users all the time but it will have to do.